# Python- Can't find a way to save a txt doc

Tags: python, save

I have a script that asks for data, then writes it into a txt document using simple file.open() and file.close() and file.write(). Every time I run the script it either doesn't save the document or overwrites it. How do I get my .txt document to reflect data from across multiple runs? If I open the document, it only contains data from my most recent run of the program. Here's the script:

```
name = input("What is your name?")

file = open("Python.txt","w") 

file.write("Next User ")
file.write(name)
file.write(" ")


ans1 = input("Which would you rather lose? a: an arm or b: a leg?")
file.write(ans1)

ans2 = input("What is your favorite primary color? a: red b: yellow c: blue")
file.write(ans2)

ans3 = input("Which do you like better? a: dogs b: cats c: birds d: hamsters e: lizards")
file.write(ans3)

ans4 = input("Do you prefer to a: talk to people b: text people or c: avoid people?")
file.write(ans4)

print("That's all for now!")
print("Here's your code: ",ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4)
print("Here's what other users got:")
file = open("Python.txt", "r") 
read = file.read()
print(read)
print("The last line is your own results.")
```

I put the `read = file.read()` in because when I use `print file.read()` it returns 'invalid syntax'. **Also: How do I have it write a return or enter key?**

Comment: Why the excessive number of blank lines? You're taking up a lot of vertical real estate!

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Use mode 'a' (for append) instead of 'w', this will add results to the end of the file instead of overwriting.

Comment: aside: you'd better explicitly `close` your write handle (or use a `with` context block)

Comment: use `print(file.read())`

Comment: Ok, so using "a" instead of "w" worked. Thanks, @jeffcarey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`open` takes a second argument, `mode`, indicating the manner in which the file should be read or written.  The default value is `"r"`, which corresponds to reading a text file.  The value suitable for appending to a text file (creating it if it doesn't exist) is `"a"`.  So do something like this.

```
with open("my-file.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write("Fun text.\n")
    f.write("More fun text!\n")
```

Comment: How do I have it type a return?

Comment: I edited the answer to put newlines between the strings.  A `\n` in a string literal produces a newline.

Comment: Great! I really could have used Stack Overflow a long time ago